# Grails 2.0: No module found with name [window]

Tags: grails, layout, grails-2.0

I am using the jQuery and Resources plugins in Grails 2.0 with the following in my layout:

```
    <g:javascript library="jquery" />
    <r:layoutResources/>
```

When clicking on a link in a view using that layout I get the following error in the console:

```
No module found with name [window]
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Jonas

Answer (score 5):

OK, I figured it out by declaring the module in Config.groovy pointing to the js file:

```
grails.resources.modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'/js/application.js'
    }
    window {
        resource url:'/js/window.js'
    }
    effects {
        resource url:'/js/effects.js'
    }
    prototype {
        resource url:'/js/prototype/prototype.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: In newer versions of grails the standard location for this is ApplicationResources.groovy.